# How to read a csv using Perl?

Tags: csv, perl

I want to read a csv using perl excluding the first row. Further, col 2 and col3 variables need to be stored in another file and the row read must be deleted.

Edit : Following code has worked. I just want the deletion part.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($field1, $field2, $field3, $line);
my $file = 'D:\Patching_test\ptch_file.csv';

open( my $data, '<', $file ) or die;
while ( $line = <$data> ) {
    next if $. == 1;
    ( $field1, $field2, $field3 ) = split ',', $line;
    print "$field1 : $field2 : $field3 ";

    my $filename = 'D:\DB_Patch.properties';
    unlink $filename;

    open( my $sh, '>', $filename )
      or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    print $sh "Patch_id=$field2\n";
    print $sh "Patch_Name=$field3";
    close($sh);

    close($data);
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: By the use of [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) Perl module you can read CSV file and do the manipulation. Please show us your code, this would help people to answer to your query.

Comment: Have edited the code.

Comment: _row read must be deleted_ - what does this means?

Comment: The row which I wrote in the property file must be deleted from the csv

Comment: @Shivani: Please edit your code to fix the indentation.

Comment: @Shivani I would suggest whatever operation you're doing on `$filename` should be done outside the `while` loop, except printing the content using `$sh` filehandler.

Comment: `close($data);` should not be inside the while loop that reads from `$data`..

Comment: If you do not move the `unlink` and `open` statement outside the loop, you will overwrite the output file every iteration. Assuming you have more than 2 lines in your input file.

Comment: Maybe the way I have written isn't much explainable. But it's working as expected except for the deletion part.

Comment: @Shivani The code you have will not affect the input file at all. It will delete and overwrite the output file 1 time per line in the input file, except the first line. Which is to say if you have 10,000 lines, you will overwrite your output file 9999 times. All the data that was in the preceding lines will be thrown away. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Shivani Actually never mind, since you `exit 0` after the 2nd line in the input file, you will only ever read line number 2 in the file. So if this code works, it is only because you expect to have exactly 2 lines in your input file. If that is incorrect, then your code is incorrect.

Comment: actually, the script get's called by a jenkins job which runs every 5 mins. Hence, the exit 0 after 1 successful read. Now, I wnt, when the job reads the csv file in the next iteration, it should not read the line which was read in the earlier iteration, thus I want to delete that line in the csv.(after it's successfully read).

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY-problem. You should probably focus the question a bit better. If you only want to know how to edit a file, just read [perldoc open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Your code only works for files which have 2 lines in them. If you expect to read more lines than that, you should probably use some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

OPs problem poorly presented for processing

- no input data sample provided
- no desired output data presented
- no modified input file after processing presented

Based on problem description following code provided

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $input   = 'D:\Patching_test\ptch_file.csv';
my $output  = 'D:\DB_Patch.properties';
my $temp    = 'D:\script_temp.dat';

open my $in, '<', $input
    or die "Couldn't open $input";

open my $out, '>', $output
    or die "Couldn't open $output";

open my $tmp, '>', $temp
    or die "Couldn't open $temp";
    
while ( <$in> ) {
    if( $. == 1 ) {
        say $tmp $_;
    } else {
        my($patch_id, $patch_name) = (split ',')[1,2];
        say $out "Patch_id=$patch_id";
        say $out "Patch_Name=$patch_name";
    }
}

close $in;
close $out;
close $tmp;

rename $temp,$input;

exit 0;
```